# form serialize() not working in Modal popup

Tags: jquery

i have to display modal popup when particular dropdown is selected,that modal contains form. i want to serialize that form. i have to try below code but it's not working please anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

`<script>$("#seldist").change(function () {if ($(this).val() == "addcust") {
modal.style.display = "block";}});</script><form class="CustForm" name="CustForm" id="CustuserForm1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"></form> <script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("button#AddCust").click(function(){var formdata=$("form[id='CustuserForm1']").serialize();alert(formdata);
$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "partials/customerAction.php",data: formdata,success: function(message){alert(message);},error: function(){alert("Error");
}});});});</script>`

Comment: use `onClick` instead of `onkeydown`

Comment: you should move away from inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to detach a handler. And never upload unformatted code. I can promise you; no one will even try to read it.

Comment: First correct your snippet

Comment: if i click tab button create new row, so i have been used onkeydown. but i onclick the delete it will remove